# MSI z390 gaming edge ac m2_1 not detected NVMe

Tags: ssd, bios, nvme, m.2

I have a MSI Z390 GAMING EDGE AC with core i9 9900k CPU, 48GB ddr4 3200 G.SKILL (2x 8GB, 2x 16Gb), 2x Samsung Evo Plus 970 (250GB, 2TB), 1x 6T SATA HDD without PCIe graphic card (yet) just onboard GPU.
I want to use my both m2 slots one (250GB Evo Plus 970) as system storage another (2TB Evo Plus 970) as gaming stuffs.
The problem is M2_1 is not detecting my SSD but I have not problem with M2_2. The HDD is unplugged. How you can fix this?

Comment: The SATA HDD is likely sharing the bandwidth of the M2_1 slot.  Check your manual for which SATA ports can be used with which M2 slots being used

Comment: @Ramhound The SATA HDD is unplugged, I want to use only M2s. Is not possible?

Comment: Your question indicates you have a 6 TB HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound for any reason may that SATA can help. I said "The HDD is unplugged." at end.

Comment: That’s just confusing people like myself

Comment: Is the BIOS set to AHCI or RAID?

Comment: @harrymc the BIOS is set to AHCI

Comment: Is the BIOS updated to the latest version?

Comment: @harrymc yes, the latest which is beta. CMOS is cleared without any changes to defaults

Comment: Just to add to 'sata is unplugged'. That does not change allocation. In the firmware (UEFI) you probably have a "PCIe lane to NVME, or PCIe lane to SATA). Unplugging a disk does not automatically change this. Instead, go to your firmware and make sure both MVME slots are activated.